# PHP form result of javascript alert opening up in different window

Tags: php, javascript

I recently made my own PHP setup for a contact form, and what I want to happen is after a user submits the form, the PHP file sends a JavaScript echo for an alert to pop up saying Thank you!, but for some reason, it opens a new window as well as a JavaScript alert.

This is the code in my PHP file:

```
<?php
$firstname = $_POST['firstName'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastName'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$tel1 = $_POST['tel1'];
$tel2 = $_POST['tel2'];
$tel3 = $_POST['tel3'];
$reason = $_POST['reason'];
$message = $_POST['text'];
$formcontent="From: $firstname $lastname \n Email address: $email \n Telephone Number: $tel1 $tel2 $tel3 \n Reason: $reason \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "ilanbiala@ilanshomekitchen.x10.mx";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "<script>alert('Thank you!');</script>";
?>
```

The last line with the echo command is where I inserted the script to alert the user with a popup upon successful submission. If you have a better idea that would be great, but I would still like to know the reason for my php causing a new window with an alert to open.

The current implementation and problem I am having can be viewed on [this site](http://ilanshomekitchen.x10.mx/contact.html).

You just have to submit form data for the form to be processed, so make sure to at least put something realistic in each box.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: where is your HTML code?

Comment: The HTML code isn't the problem because I am trying to get the 2nd to last line in my php not to open a new window and bring up a popup but just bring up a popup on the current form at the link in my question.

Comment: It sounds like you want an ajax form.

Answer (score 1):

```
$( function() { // $(document).ready( function() { }); this function prepares itself to be attentive to listen an event when the DOM is ready
$("#form").on("submit", function(e) { // As the form is submitted, the function is executed
e.preventDefault(); // this prevents the form to be submitted as default behaviour!
var s = $(this).serialize();  // makes a string which has all form's data in this form e.g. ?id=1&name=Heart
$.ajax({ // create an jQuery ajax call
     url : 'mail.php'+s, // this will transfer data to the mail.php. In mail.php, use $_GET with all variables
     cache : false, // changing browser cache
     success : function(data) { // success means when the ajax completed transfer of variables and that function with data as an argument is callback variable which stores all the information echoed in php file
          alert(data); // now you can manipulate that variable, i use alert function
     },
     error : function() { // this function checks if error occurs in the ajax transfer, if yes, then execute a certain function!
          alert("Form Not Submitted"); // I have just alerted not submitted!
     };
 });
 });
```

You will also have to include jQuery Latest Version Which can be found [Here](http://www.jquery.com)

Comment: well, i had given a long description. otherwise, i can explain little bit more!

Comment: You forgot to stop the form from submitting.

Comment: well @llan Biala i have added too much comments to help you but you have to struggle yourself to understand them! if you say then i can change the above code in JAVASCRIPT but it will be too big. Bro, You have to start from somewhere otherwise you can't rely on others!

Answer (score 0):

You are submitting a form to mail.php, so the mail.php will process the html request and print the page. The page that is being submitted by you is `<script>alert('Thank you!');</script>`

It seems that you don't want to open a new page, so you can make an ajax call to the mail.php page and you can call an alert once the form has been submitted succesfully.

jQuery has a [ajax function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or a [post function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Comment: I changed it to jQuery after I noticed it was in your source

Comment: it alerts me on the same window!

Comment: if you want not to page to be redirected then you have to use ajax() function which you have not!

Comment: please wait some time, making a tutorial for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML ***is*** the problem.

```
<form id="form" action="mail.php" method="post">
```

That is on 'contact.html', so when you submit the form, it loads 'mail.php'.

You want an AJAX form, or at the least, load the form on the same page.  Using jQuery, you can do something like:

```
$('.submitButton').click(function(){
    $.get('mail.php',$("#form").serialize(), function(data){
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

At the very least, you can put the mail.php code at the top of the contact page and add a check to see if a form was submitted (`if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){}`)  You would need to update contact.html to contact.php, and then redirect the form to 'contact.php' instead of 'mail.php'.  Then the mail would load on the same page, the alert will appear and the content will appear as well, may take some tweaking, but you can get it right.

Good luck.

Comment: can you explain the code...I am not very familiar with the jQuery language.

Comment: jQuery is a library.  Javascript is the language.  It basically takes the class submitButton and then executes a AJAX get function to your mail.php page and then executes a function based on the data retrieved.  You can probably find one or two tutorials online pretty easily.

Comment: I explained it fairly well.  I am not going to walk you through it step by step as you can read up on jQuery and figure out pretty easily what is going on.  Don't expect SO users to do all your work for you.  We are here to point you in the right direction and fix any errors along the way.

Comment: As far as performance, AJAX looks smoother, but they are equal performance wise.  Each one will make a call to a new page, so it is truly up to you.  AJAX requires more work, but can definitely add to the user experience.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code:
In Mail.php

```
$_SESSION['mail_msg']="Thank You";
header("Location: contact.php");
```

Save contact.html as contact.php and add following code

```
if(isset($_SESSION['mail_msg'])){
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert("{$_SESSION['mail_msg']}")</script>";
}
```

Don't forget to start session on both files.